# MySQL - Рекламные кампании и блеклист

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Есть 2 таблицы "**campaigns**" и "**bl_sites**"

```
campaigns        bl_sites
---------        ---------
id               camp_id
status           site
```

Данные в таблице "**bl_sites**".
ID кампании и перечень сайтов на которых данную рекламную кампанию показывать не нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеем сайт "**ajax.loc**" 
Нужно выбрать все кампании и исключить с выборки кампании у которых в блэклисте присутствует сайт "**ajax.loc**".
В данном случае нужно исключить кампанию с **ID 21**

---

Такой запрос не работает

```
SELECT * FROM camps
LEFT JOIN bl_sites ON bl_sites.camp_id = camps.id
WHERE bl_sites.site != 'ajax.loc'
```

Он просто исключает из объединенной выборки строки, у которых **bl_sites.site = 'ajax.loc'** 
Мало того, он вообще не включает в выборку кампании у которых нет сайтов в блеклисте (нет записей в таблице "bl_sites")

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Такой запрос так же не работает

```
SELECT * FROM camps
LEFT JOIN bl_sites ON bl_sites.camp_id = camps.id
WHERE bl_sites.site != 'ajax.loc' OR bl_sites.site IS NULL
```

Он уже включает те кампании у которых нет блеклиста. Но все равно оставляет кампанию с ID 21

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверное я что-то делаю не так. Думал уже плюнуть и добавить текстовое поле в таблицу с кампаниями и писать туда сайты через запятую (для каждой кампании свой БЛ). При выборке использовать LIKE.

Comment: В ON напишите `bl_sites.site = 'ajax.loc'` что бы этот join подклеивал только записи с ajax.loc, а в where только одно условие `bl_sites.site IS NULL`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT camp_id FROM bl_sites WHERE site = 'ajax.loc');` должно работать

Comment: Да! Способ с подзапросом работает.

Comment: Без подзапроса то же должен `SELECT * FROM camps
LEFT JOIN bl_sites ON bl_sites.camp_id = camps.id and bl_sites.site = 'ajax.loc' WHERE bl_sites.site IS NULL`.